# Firebase functions how to get a boolean value from Firebase Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a code in node.js in the functions of Firebase, that simply what I want to know is how to get the Boolean value of the variable "read" within each user within the class "Users".

My code:

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotificationNewChat = functions.database.ref('/Usuarios/{usuarioId}/Chats/{chatsId}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    //get the userId of the person receiving the notification because we need to get their token
//const receiverId = context.params.userId;
//console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);
/*
    // Only edit data when it is first created.
      if (change.before.exists()) {
        return null;
      }*/
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
      }

    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    //te escribe el json de el mensaje nuevo
    const afterData = change.after.val();
    console.log("afterData: ", afterData);

  //  const readChat = afterData.read;
   // console.log("readChat: ", readChat);


//get the user id of the person who sent the message
    const senderId = context.params.usuarioId;
    console.log("senderId: ", senderId);

//get the user id of the person who sent the message
    const receiverId = afterData.IdOtherUser;
    console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);


//get the message
    const nameAd = afterData.nameAd;
    console.log("nameAd: ", nameAd);


//get the message
    const ChatId = context.params.chatsId;
    console.log("ChatId: ", ChatId);

    /*
    //get the message id. We'll be sending this in the payload
    const messageId = context.params.messageId;
    console.log("messageId: ", messageId);
    */
    return admin.database().ref("/Usuarios/"+senderId+"/Chats/"+ChatId).once('value').then(snap => {
        const readChat = snap.child("read").val();
       // if (readChat) return null
        console.log("readChat: ", readChat);



//query the users node and get the name of the user who sent the message
    return admin.database().ref("/Usuarios/" + senderId).once('value').then(snap => {
        const senderName = snap.child("name").val();
        console.log("senderName: ", senderName);

//get the token of the user receiving the message
        return admin.database().ref("/Usuarios/" + receiverId).once('value').then(snap => {

            const receiverName = snap.child("name").val();
            console.log("receiverName: ", receiverName);

            const token = snap.child("token").val();
            console.log("token: ", token);

//we have everything we need
//Build the message payload and send the message
            console.log("Construction the notification message.");
            const payload = {
                data: {
                    data_type: "direct_message",
                    title: "Nueva conversación de " + senderName,
                    message: "Selecciona para ver los mensajes",
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    return console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });
        });
    });
});
});
```

I use this part of code to get the read value but always the records of firebase function tells me that it gets null value 
Part of code to get the boolean value from "read":

```
admin.database().ref("/Usuarios/"+senderId+"/Chats/"+ChatId).once('value').then(snap => {
            const readChat = snap.child("read").val();
           // if (readChat) return null
            console.log("readChat: ", readChat);
```

[image: the records of firebase function]

Comment: Could you pls add the exact structure of your database and, if possible, an export of the data (Use the three dots button in the top right corner of the Firebase console when you are on the RTDB module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snap.val() will return an object so you can object and store it in a variable and try access it or otherwise try like below

```
admin.database().ref("/Usuarios/"+senderId+"/Chats/"+ChatId).once('value')           
.then(snap => {              
        if(snap.numChildren() === 0) // check for no data available              
        snap.child("read").val(); // instead of this line write like below
        const readChat =  **snap.val()[read];** or **snap.val().read**
       // if (readChat) return null
        console.log("readChat: ", readChat);
})
```

// Considering this your structure

```
---user
-----senderId
--------Chats
-----------ChatId
---------------read: true
```

the above code will do